# C# SelectSingleNode with NameSpace issues

Tags: c#, xml, selectsinglenode

I am using C# (.NET 2.0) -- actually trying to have it working on Mac OS X using MONO (I don't think MONO is the issue)

Given the following XML fragment which has been retrieved as a XmlNode from a bigger XmlDocument:

```
<subcategoryCode xmlns="uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992">N100</subcategoryCode>
<subcategoryName xmlns="uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992">DJ Headphones</subcategoryName>
<products xlink:href="tcm:5-33975" xlink:title="TESTONE Composition" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992" />
<products xlink:href="tcm:5-54295" xlink:title="HPX2000 Composition" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992" />
<products xlink:href="tcm:5-54296" xlink:title="HPX4000 Composition" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992" />
```

I am trying to retrieve subcategoryName using SelectSingleNode but I simply cannot. This is my code:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992");

XmlNodeList subcatList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("subcategories");

foreach (XmlNode subcat in subcatList) {
  html += "<div id=\"";
  html += subcat.SelectSingleNode("subcategoryName", nsm).InnerText; // <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM!!!
  html += "\" class=\"product_thumbs_holder\" style=\"display: block; \">";
  html += "</div>";
  html += "<div style=\"clear:both\"></div>";
}
```

I believe the issue is probably related to the way I am handling the Namespace but I have been stuck on this for hours. I have tried a bunch of similar AddNamespace declarations with no luck.

Anyone out there would be kind enough to provide any pointers to where the issue is?

Comment: Where are you adding your namespace manager to the XMLDocument??

Comment: @Furqan I am not sure... The variable "doc" is an XmlDocument object that I receive as a parameter in a function, then I do this:

`private static string generateTridionRightPaneCode(XmlDocument doc) {
  XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
  nsm.AddNamespace("uuid", "uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992");`

Is that enough?


THANK YOU

Comment: Where are the subcategories elements in your fragment. You are retrieving them using this: XmlNodeList subcatList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("subcategories");
but there aren't any such elements, your nodelist should be empty

Comment: @Embo I have not included the whole XML file which includes a few "subcategories" elements; the first XML snippet that I posted is the contents of subcatlist as viewed on the debugger. The nodelist is *not* empty.

Answer (score 1):

XPath doesn't work with default namespaces. You must create a prefix for the namespace. This code should work:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("x", "uuid:7E1158D2-DA42-4048-8513-66B4D48FA992");

XmlNodeList subcatList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("subcategories");

foreach (XmlNode subcat in subcatList) {
    html += "<div id=\"";
    html += subcat.SelectSingleNode("x:subcategoryName", nsm).InnerText; // <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM!!!
    html += "\" class=\"product_thumbs_holder\" style=\"display: block; \">";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "<div style=\"clear:both\"></div>";
}
```

**Note:** you don't need to add the prefix in de xml document. The prefixes in the xml document and the prefixes in the code don't have to match, as long as the associated namespaces match.

Comment: +1 the code does work and is long overdue an up-vote and should have got the green tick! Nice note too.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `subcategoryName` directly:

```
XmlNodeList subcatList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName( "subcategoryName" );
foreach( XmlNode subcat in subcatList )
{
    Console.WriteLine( subcat.InnerText );
}
```

This will get all of the `subcategoryName` elements in the xml file.